# What options are available to the options array of the doesBucketExist function in the S3Client class?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm looking at the php S3Client class documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesBucketExist), specifically the `doesBucketExist` function.  The docs show that you can pass in an options array to the function, but not what those options are.  Does anyone know what the options are for this function, or where I can find them?